# Foreach and sleep function to broadcast

Tags: laravel, websocket, sleep, broadcast, laravel-artisan

The main objective of this question is to have a system running permanently on the server to broadcast music.

I would like to create an artisan console function that will automatically launch a track from its parent game every 32 seconds. Unfortunately the sleep() function blocks the parent loop.

Two questions (or maybe three):
What would be the solution to prevent the parent loop from stopping?
Does this method consume too many resources? Is there a better way?

```
public function fetch($games) {

    foreach ($games as $game) {

        $tracks = Track::inRandomOrder()->where('game_id', $game->id)->limit($game->tracks_number)->get();

        foreach ($tracks as $key => $track) {

             broadcast(new NewTrack($track));

             if($key + 1  == count($tracks)) {
                 $this->fetch($this->games);
             }

             sleep(32);

         }

    }

}
```

Many thanks for your feedback

Comment: How do you know the parent loop is stopping? Do you receive any errors?

Comment: I know it because i don't get the broadcasts from other games, Only from the first one.

Comment: Append `set_time_limit(0);` before `foreach` and try again.

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work